# Can you make a user-based search with Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api, search

On Facebook when you write something in the search box in the top.

> Like 'Eric'

You first get the results with your friends named Eric and further down you get people you might know with X mutual friends and some random people in the vicinity you might know.

Is it possible to make a similar search with the Facebook API?

I've tried:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=eric&type=user&fields=id,name&access_token= (my token)
```

And thought if I added my access_token I would get a search like the one on Facebook. But I just get some random Eric's from all over the world.

I'm writing a simple web application and getting this search to work would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to an extent but before looking further ensure this isn't the main service of your app otherwise you run the risk of violating Facebook policy on replicating core functionality.

You need to look into the [user FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) and the [friend table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend)

Do an FQL call as follow:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

Then save the JSON response from that call and use a typeahead algorithm / plugin.