# facebook API search user relevant to user token

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, search

So basicaly the question is the same as [Can you make a user-based search with Facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451817/can-you-make-a-user-based-search-with-facebook-api)

the difference is that FQL is not supported already in FB

So againe how to use fb graph api search to find users relevant to user that use search api call.
When i do v2.3/search?q=Leo+Luo&type=user and i do have Leo Luo in friends i get over 500+ of Leo. But relevant Leo to me is in 200+ place!  Not in the first as it in FB ui search

Answer (score 0):

Public Post search has been deprecated since April 30th 2014 with Graph API v2.0.

I believe this also affects user searches.

See

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Comment: yep that sad. search for users is not obsolete but its not as good as in Facebook page.